# How to create jenkins job for robot framework API python tests on Unix platform

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I am setting up Robot framework for rest API testing using python. I have Jenkins server hosted and i want to enable remote machine execution.

I am using Pycharm IDE to develop Robot framework rest api test cases.
also i am using Ubuntu/Unix platform to develop.
I have Jenkins already hosted on a server. i.e jenkins..com and i have my framework on ubuntu VM. How to configure a jenkins job so that the job logs into ubuntu machine or in that case any remote machine and start executing the test?

I have configured Build -> Execute Shell ->

```
cp -R cp -R /home/<User>/Documents/<Project>/ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<Project>
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project>/robot -r ./Reports/report.html -l ./Reports/log.html -o ./Reports/output.xml --listener "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project>;<Slack Integration webhook ID>;<Slack Channel name>" /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RiskSenseAPIAutomation/<Project test class>
```

Getting an error when triggered a job

```
/tmp/jenkins7826430919602606012.sh: 3: /tmp/jenkins7826430919602606012.sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<Project>/robot: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is your folder really named `<Project>`, or are you expecting jenkins to substitute the actual folder? Also, is the `robot` command actually in the root of your project?

Comment: It is project path

Comment: So, your job is expecting to find a file named 'robot' in the literal path `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<project>/robot`, and it's telling you it doesn't exist. Jenkins won't give you that error unless the file literally doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

This should be a simple setup for the jenkins build environment. If you want to run a jenkins job on a remote machine you will need to set the jenkins slave service or any other option to configure the remote node. Below are some links that can help you on how to configure remote nodes on Ubuntu.

**How to configure Remote Slave on Ubuntu**

1. https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/12/22/jenkins-configuring-a-linux-slave-node
2. https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-setup-jenkins-master-and-slave-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Once you configure the Remote Node then Edit the configuration of your job to use **"Restrict where this project can be run"** open to adding Node label that you assigned while configuring the Node in the previous step. Here is a link that can also help you to understand how you can configure your job to run on a specific agent or node

http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/teamforge171/action/runjob_usinglmtemplate.html.

**Please note :** The option **"Restrict where this project can be run"** will not be available in job configuration page until you have a remote node configured on jenkins.